# How can I divide my table view data in sections alphabetically using Swift? (rewritten)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, sorting, uilocalizedcollation

I have a data source in this form:

```
struct Country {
    let name: String
}
```

The other properties won't come into play in this stage so let's keep it simple.

I have separated ViewController and TableViewDataSource in two separate files. Here is the Data source code:

```swift
class CountryDataSource: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource {
    var countries = [Country]()
    var filteredCountries = [Country]()
    var dataChanged: (() -> Void)?
    var tableView: UITableView!

    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

    var filterText: String? {
        didSet {
            filteredCountries = countries.matching(filterText)
            self.dataChanged?()
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return filteredCountries.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        let country: Country

        country = filteredCountries[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = country.name

        return cell
    }
}
```

As you can see there is already a filtering mechanism in place. 
Here is the most relevant part of the view controller:

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController, URLSessionDataDelegate {
    let dataSource = CountryDataSource()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        dataSource.tableView = self.tableView
        dataSource.dataChanged = { [weak self] in
            self?.tableView.reloadData()
        }

        tableView.dataSource = dataSource

        // Setup the Search Controller
        dataSource.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        dataSource.searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        dataSource.searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search countries..."
        navigationItem.searchController = dataSource.searchController
        definesPresentationContext = true

        performSelector(inBackground: #selector(loadCountries), with: nil)
    }
```

The `loadCountries` is what fetches the JSON and load the table view inside the `dataSource.countries` and `dataSource.filteredCountries` array.

Now, how can I get the indexed collation like the Contacts app has without breaking all this? 
I tried several tutorials, no one worked because they were needing a `class` data model or everything inside the view controller.
All solutions tried either crash (worst case) or don't load the correct data or don't recognise it...

Please I need some help here.
Thank you

Comment: Please [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+alphabetically+section). There are a lot of related questions

Comment: I know :-( ... but they are all old and most of them including Objective-C. I would like to know if using data as struct would be possible.

Comment: Yes, it's possible.

Comment: Could you kindly point me to a question that solves this? (I'm looking at your link while waiting)... I promise I'll close the question if I find it, but I searched before writing...

Comment: A concrete suggestion depends on your design. Please read the answers in my search query.

Comment: I'm reading this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41646933/how-do-you-sort-data-in-a-tableview-alphabetically-by-section-using-a-custom-mod — it could work. Just how do I put this in my UITableViewDataSource class instead of the ViewController? Sorry, first time I refactor my code this way.

Comment: I have no idea, I don't know the code.

Comment: I have edited the question with some code and more description, let me know if you can help me now. Thanks. I tried that question in the meantime and no, it doesn't work because my model is a struct...

Comment: I tried many solutions, no one works or it is too complex for the simplicity I seek. Would it be of help if I would change my question to something like: “How to sort my table view alphabetically if I have the data source separated from the view controller?”. Is this any clearer? @vadian

Comment: I managed to solve it, using NONE of the solutions suggested in ANY of the questions that were suggested. Should I close the question or is someone suddenly interested in apparently the only solution that could work in this configuration?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to work with CellViewModels instead of model data.
Steps:

1) Create an array per word with your cell view models sorted alphabetically. If you have data for A, C, F, L, Y and Z you are going to have 6 arrays with cell view models. I'm going to call them as "sectionArray".

2) Create another array and add the sectionArrays sorted alphabetically, the "cellModelsData". So, The cellModelsData is an array of sectionArrays.

3) On numberOfSections return the count of cellModelsData.

4) On numberOfRowsInSection get the sectionArray inside the cellModelsData according to the section number (cellModelsData[section]) and return the count of that sectionArray.

5) On cellForRowAtindexPath get the sectionArray (cellModelsData[indexPath.section]) and then get the "cellModel" (sectionArray[indexPath.row]). Dequeue the cell and set the cell model to the cell.

I think that this approach should resolve your problem.

I made a sample project in BitBucket that could help you: https://bitbucket.org/gastonmontes/reutilizablecellssampleproject

Example:
You have the following words:
Does.
Any.
Visa.
Count.
Refused.
Add.
Country.

1)

SectionArrayA: [Add, Any]

SectionArrayC: [Count, Country]

SectionArrayR: [Refused]

SectionArrayV: [Visa]

2)

cellModelsData = [ [SectionArrayA], [SectionArrayC], [SectionArrayR], [SectionArrayV] ]

3)

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return self.cellModelsData.count
}
```

4)

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let sectionModels = self.cellModelsData[section]
    return sectionModels.count
}
```

5)

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let sectionModels = self.cellModelsData[indexPath.section]
    let cellModel = sectionModels[indexPath.row]

    let cell = self.sampleCellsTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "YourCellIdentifier",
                                                             for: indexPath) as! YourCell
    cell.cellSetModel(cellModel)

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This looks really overkill for my app. I just need alphabetical sectioning for my model which is a struct and that has already filtering implemented with the UISearchBarController...